# Null SOAP Value

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, zend-soap

I'm using Zend's Soap Client to submit a SOAP request to a proxy server and I'm having issues getting the return value.

if i print out the ojbect $response->responseMessage[0] I get the following

```
Response: SoapVar Object
(
    [enc_type] => 0
    [enc_value] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 126
            [message] => No Field Values 
        )

    [enc_stype] => responseMessage
    [enc_ns] => urn:Turbolink
)
```

But when I print $response->responseMessage[0]->code I get a null value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't using a property that exists. As you can see in the sample output, the property is: `$response->responseMessage[0]->enc_value->code` -- you're missing the `enc_value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$response->responseMessage[0]->enc_value->code`

Comment: why didn't i think of that.  -- facepalm -- thank you.